# Create and join channel error ; Hypereldger fabric tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to a tutorial of hyperledger fabric on Mac. (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#create-join-channel)
At 'Create & Join Channel' part, I have 2 questions.

1.I typed `export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel`, but there is apparently no change. What does this command mean?

2.And later, I typed`peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem` , the following error occurred. What if I do, the problem will be resolved?(There seems to be no such directory, so do I have to create? )

> [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp folder

Accordingly, I use Mac and installed all of the guided resources yesterday or day before yesterday, so I think resource version is correct.

I'd appreciate if you could answer these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: `export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel` Sets the CHANNEL_NAME variable to "mychannel".

Following that tutorial you linked, this just sets the variable ($CHANNEL_NAME) they have in their command: 
`peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME`

However, you are right when you say changing that does nothing because you have hardcoded "mychannel" in your peer channel create command. Both your way and the tutorial way will have the same end result.

Question 2: The directory below points to where the peer certificates for the MSP are supposed to be, in your example. These files are generated with the `../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml` command from the tutorial. The error message is saying that the peer is unable to start due to that directory not existing, or containing the needed certs. I would ensure the peer container has those certs in that location, one way would be to Docker exec into it.

> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful.
Q1 is resolved, but please tell me more about Q2.
I typed your command `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp` , the result was `No such file or directory`.
And I checked  `../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml` , and the result was following:
`org1.example.com
org2.example.com`
This is the same as the tutorial guides, I think.
But there is not generated directory I want.
What's happening?